# Exporting ArrayPlot as PNG (where each value in the array defines one pixel)

Tags: plotting, export, cellular-automata

relatively new to Wolfram/Mathematica. I'm using wolframscript on ubuntu, and trying to export various Two-Color Automata as PNG files. It works fine for 50 evolutions, but when I do 500 or so, it is saving as gray-scale - even tho the array has only 0s and 1s. In Python, I was able to make CAs as big as I wanted, and I simply saved them as PNG files where each tuple defined a single pixel. It works if I create the CA in WolframCloud and simply right-click the image and save, but I need to do this for 1000s of images - so that's not practical. Here is an example, produced by this:

```
Export["zebra.png", ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 500]]]
```

[image]

Is there no way to "directly" create a PNG image from array-data, where each element in the array defines one pixel of the image, as in Python?

Comment: You should replace `ArrayPlot` with `Image`.

Comment: thanks, that actually did work, now it's a binary image, but the colors are reversed...?

Comment: @panawe, there was `PixelConstrained` option for `ArrayPlot`, which is obsolete as of v12.1, but it still works: `ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {64, 64}], PixelConstrained -> 1]  // Options // First`

Answer (score 2):

Generate a 501x1001 array:

```
A = CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 500];
Dimensions[A]
(*    {501, 1001}    *)
```

Export one pixel per matrix entry:

```
Export["~/Desktop/zebra.png", Image[Raster[Reverse[A]]]]
```

The resulting image has exactly 1001x501 pixels, each one either black (=0) or white (=1) (opposite color scheme from `ArrayPlot`):

[image]

If you want the inverted color scheme, just export `1-A` instead of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `ImageSize`. Here us an example and an enlarged piece of the resulting picture:

```
n = 500;
ar = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], {n}, {n}];
Export["d:/tmp/test.png", ArrayPlot[ar, ImageSize -> 2000]]
```

[image]

The same with "GameOfLive":

```
n = 500;
ar = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], {n}, {n}];
gol = CellularAutomaton["GameOfLife", ar]
Export["d:/tmp/test.png", ArrayPlot[gol, ImageSize -> 2000]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply; I can get it to work for an array of RandomIntegers that are either 0 or 1, but not for the CellularAutomaton function, even with trying ImageSize->2000....is there something specific to the CA function that is causing it? even if I look at the actual data within the array created by the CA function, it's just 0s and 1s, but it always produces a grayscale image.

Comment: I added an example using: `CellularAutomaton`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's input, but I ended up just iterating over the array and replacing each integer with a tuple, which gave me the control I wanted. This way I can do an arbitrary number of colors for the CAs and control each integer's output-color.

```
Do[
  If[A[[z]][[y]] == 0, 
    B[[z]][[y]] = RGBColor["White"],
    B[[z]][[y]] = RGBColor["Green"]
  ], 
  {z, Length[A]}, {y, Length[A[[z]]]}
]
```

Comment: I think you could achieve the same goal with a replacement `ca = CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 500]; ca /. {0 -> RGBColor["White"], _?NumberQ -> RGBColor["Green"]}`. Iterating over an array is rarely the most direct way to achieve your goal in Mathematica.